# TFS is not picking up DLLs installed through nuget

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, nuget

It seems whenever a package is installed through nuget TFS doesn't pick up the dlls files for that pacakge and it's becoming a pain working on the project with multiple developers when new DLLs are being added and old ones updated.?

The 'packages' folder is being checked in.

I've searched google and seem to find people with the same problem but no solution.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: are you checking in the packages.config file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest *not* checking in the *packages* folder, and instead [enable Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages).

Comment: I wish I could bold the 'not checking in the packages folder'

Answer (score 2):

Check out [TFS NuGetter](http://nugetter.codeplex.com/), an integrated NuGet solution into TFS build process.